# aggregation string in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame where one column is string names (v1), and the second column is string values(v2), I would like to aggregate those entries and sum their string values.(V1 and V2 are list)

V1 and V2 are list

trp_str

```
    V1  V2

1 a,x,v 0.07128713

2  b,x,c  0.06336634

3  c,x,v  0.04752475

4 c,x,v  0.04752475

5 d,x,v  0.06336634

6 a,x,v 0.07128713

i want to get like this
  V1     V2
1 a,x,v 0.14257426

2  b,x,c  0.06336634

3  c,x,v  0.0950495

4  d,x,v  0.06336634
```

when i used aggregate(trp_str$V1, by=list(V2=trp_str$V2), FUN=sum) following error occured
Error in aggregate.data.frame(as.data.frame(x), ...) : 
  arguments must have same length

Comment: dput() of sample data

Comment: u can directly use aggregate function right?

Comment: Pretty sure there are lot of answers for this question already, but you want `aggregate`. Or the `dplyr` package (`group_by` + `summarise`) or the built-in aggregation capabilities of the `data.table` package

Comment: when i used aggregate(trp_str$V1, by=list(V2=trp_str$V2), FUN=sum) following error occured
Error in aggregate.data.frame(as.data.frame(x), ...) : 
  arguments must have same length

Comment: @KiranPg provide reproducible example. I think you need `aggregate(trp_str$V2, by=list(V1=trp_str$V1), FUN=sum)`

Comment: aggregate(trp_str$V2, by=list(V1=trp_str$V1), FUN=sum)
it show   Error in aggregate.data.frame(as.data.frame(x), ...) : 
  arguments must have same length

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple operation. A lot of it already has been answered on this site

This should work for you

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(V1 = c('a,x,v','b,x,c', 'c,x,v', 'c,x,v', 'd,x,v', 'a,x,v'), 
                 V2 = c(0.07128713, 0.06336634, 0.04752475, 0.04752475, 0.06336634,0.07128713))

df %>% group_by(V1) %>% summarise(Total = sum(V2))
```

Basically, you group by V1 column, then use the `summarise` function to `sum` up the values in V2 column. Here, I named the column that holds the sums `Total` but you can name it whatever you want.

Comment: when i apply this show      Error in grouped_df_impl(data, unname(vars), drop) : 
  Column `V1` can't be used as a grouping variable because it's a list

Comment: if you have your data in a list format, convert it to a dataframe. I thought you said you have a dataframe.